# PostgreSQL get json key name after comparing values of keys

Tags: postgresql, query, jsonb

I have table which has a column of type json with name "demographic". I want to compare keys(predefined by me)  by their values and the result of that should be the name of the key and not the value which later i will use to save to another column's rows.

The json columns  that i have and want to compare values looks like  this:

```json
{
   "he":{
      "he_vakiy":29384,
      "he_naiset":14803,
      "he_miehet":14581,
      "he_kika":1485,
      "he_0_2":850,
      "he_3_6"
   }
}
```

I want to compare f.ex "he_naiset" and "he_miehet" and the one that has highest value should return the name of the "key" ;

Ive tried something like this:

```
select greatest(demographics->'he'->>'he_miehet',demographics->'he'->>'he_naiset') as greatest 
from demographics;
```

Which will compare the values and return the highest values. But I don't know how I can get the name of the key.

I also tried something like this from:

```
with cte as
(
   select *
        , genre.key as genre
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) as ord
     from base.maakunta
    cross
     join lateral json_each_text(base.maakunta.demographic->'he') genre

)
select  genre, value,ord
  from cte
where ord = 1
;
```

But this one compares all the keys inside the JSON.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed. Are you using `json` or `jsonb`? *"But this one compares all the keys inside the json."* I'm confused: isn't that what you want? What is your expected result for the above JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to look at two keys, add a WHERE clause to limit the rows returned by the `json_each_text()` function:

```
with cte as
(
   select *
        , genre.key as genre
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by value::int desc) as ord
    from base.maakunta
      cross join lateral json_each_text(base.maakunta.demographic->'he') genre
    where genre.key in ('he_miehet', 'he_naiset') --<< limit to the keys you want to check
)
select  genre, value,ord
from cte
where ord = 1
;
```